# What environment is my jupyter notebook runninng on when I launch it from my terminal?

Tags: python

I am using a conda environment when I launch `jupyter notebook`, and my environment has Python 3.8 installed.

However, when I launch the notebook and try to import packages, I get (note the LAST LINE):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-2b...8b8> in <module>
----> 1 from blah import reference

~/work/blah/blah/__init__.py in <module>
     64 
     65 # Private methods for use here
---> 66 from ._internals.api import configure as _configure
     67 from ._internals.api.utils.warnings import PatchWarning as _PatchWarning
     68 

~/work/blah/blah/_internals/api/configure.py in <module>
     10 from typeguard import typechecked
     11 
---> 12 from blah._internals.rest import user
     13 from blah._internals.api.utils.authentication import get_token
     14 from blah._internals.api.utils.exceptions import BmllError

~/work/blah/blah/_internals/rest.py in <module>
     13 from functools import wraps
     14 from http import HTTPStatus
---> 15 from typing import Dict, Optional, TypedDict
     16 
     17 from requests import request

ImportError: cannot import name 'TypedDict' from 'typing' (/home/pchong/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/typing.py)
```

From the last line it is clear that it is using python3.7??

Comment: What's the output of `platform.python_version()`?

Comment: Should I run this in the notebook? I need to import platform?

Comment: Yes, import `platform` and run it.

Comment: ohhh it says `'3.7.6'`

Comment: But what env is it using then? I am quite confused. I thought the notebook uses the env from which I launched it from in my terminal? Seems this is not the case.

Comment: And what does `python -VV` print (run in termial when in env)?

Comment: Python 3.8.15 (default, Nov 24 2022, 15:19:38) 
[GCC 11.2.0]

Comment: Then you can try to run `python -m jupyter notebook` and check `platform.python_version()`.

Comment: It's `3.7.6` when I do the above.

Comment: How did you create the venv? Did you use something like `conda create --name some_name -c anaconda python=3.8`?

Comment: Exactly that actually.

Comment: And then you activated it, installed jupyter and run it?

Comment: If I exit all environments my python V is 3.7 so it does make sense. How can I upgrade it to 3.8? I tried doing `sudo apt install python3.8` but this didn't upgrade it.

Comment: Yes that's right. I just activated it and ran it.

Comment: And how did you install it? Could you please describe all steps in the question?

Comment: How did I install python?

Comment: All steps I mean - create env, activate, install jupyter, run it.

Comment: Before that, is it okay that my executable is python 3.7? Can I not just upgrade to 3.8 and see if it works?

Comment: I did those things a long time ago, not sure I rememebr what steps I followed- they were all from the internet

Comment: In your env its 3.8 (as returned by `python -VV`). Can you run `python -m pip install jupyter ipykernel` and check if its already installed?

Comment: Yes it says the requirements are all already satisfied.

Comment: the notebook is clealry using the executable, so can I not just upgrade python?

Answer (score 1):

If you can see the import error path it says python 3.7, So by default the jupyter notebook runs on the python environment you installed using conda, you can easily solve this issue by creating a virtual conda environment using
`conda create -n yourenvname python=3.8` and then launch jupyter notebook from that terminal.

Tip: VS code does this very smoothly

Answer (score 0):

You can run jupyter notebook using desired version by:

```
<path_to_python> -m jupyter notebook
```

Comment: What does `<path_to_python>` represent in this case? Path to my python env? As far as I can see inside my conda python3.8 is a directory, so if I run the above with the path to the directory it doesn't work.

Comment: Its path to the python executable.

Comment: My executables only contain python3.7!

Comment: Can I just install python3.8?

Comment: It should be something like `<env_path>/bin/python`.