# How to choose my python version from `python` + ``tab``

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I type `python` into my terminal and hit tab, I see this:

```
python             python3.10         python3.7          python3.7m         python3.8          python-dotenv      
python3            python3.10-config  python3.7-config   python3.7m-config  python3-config
```

I am trying to use my python 3.8, but I can't seem to do this.

When I run `python -V` I get:

```
Python 3.7.6
```

Any ideas how to use the python 3.8?

Comment: What about `python3.8 -V`?

Comment: `Python 3.8.16`

Comment: The reason I raised this is because when I run `jupyter notebook`, it uses the 3.7 version.

Comment: The plain `python` is probably a symlink pointing to the real executable. On debian-based distributions this is manged by `update-alternatives`. You might want to look into that.

Comment: Glad that's out. Next time, please please please ask: "how can I make jupyter notebook use the right python version?" and not what you asked. Makes life easier for everyone.

Comment: @ebuwqfjeb please add jupyter into the question headline and maybe tag.

Comment: You've already asked this question in different ways twice before. https://stackoverflow.com/q/75683267/839733 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/75756453/839733

Comment: ... and finally let us know what OS you are using. I was stabbing in the dark with debian-based. Hermann12 guesses it might be Windows. Don't let people guess stuff, tell them!

Answer (score 0):

The shell shows you the possible completions to show what more you can type to get a valid command. Just continue typing to disambiguate the string and select the right command, in this case `python3.8`. Because of the way these alternatives are named, you have to type the remainder yourself. In other cases, when only one completion is available, the tab completion will fill in the rest of the command name once you type enough characters, in many shells.

To make a particular Python version your preferred one, you can manipulate your `PATH` to put its directory before the others, or, in many shells, define an alias pointing to the one you want.

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python-3.8/bin/python3.8
```

Aliases have many problems, so for anything less trivial, probably prefer a shell function or a script.

Another way to manage your Python versions is to use virtual environments. There are third-party helpers like `pyenv` which let you choose a Python version for each project or directory, or play around with different versions without messing with the `PATH`.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/python-3.8/bin/python3.8` is obviously a stab in the dark; the real path of your `python3.8` is not visible from your question, but you can try `type python3.8` to have the shell print it out.

Answer (score -1):

You have to install `python -m pip install ipykernel` and `python -m ipykernel install --user`. Than go to C:\Users\your_name\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\python3. You will find a file **kernel.json** with the used python path, like:

```
{
 "argv": [
  "C:\\Python39\\python.exe",  # This is your path what you can set up
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3 (ipykernel)",
 "language": "python",
 "metadata": {
  "debugger": true
 }
}
```

After restart `jupyter notebook` the new python environment will be used. You can than check your set up, within jupyter:

```
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())
```

Comment: This is an answer to entirely a different question.

Comment: @tripleee please read his comment above, He is interessted for jupyter not python. I comment him, he should change the title.

Comment: The actual question the OP asked is specifically and unequivocally about what happens in the terminal. Their earlier questions actually seem to be about Jupyter; I have no trouble imagining that that's what they are actually struggling with, but it is not what they ended up asking about.